# Debian WiFi firmware missing

Tags: debian, wifi, firmware

**Issue**

Upon installing Debian I received no errors/warnings or otherwise informing me about missing drivers. However when I boot in and go to wifi settings, I'm told "firmware missing" in the top bar.

**Attempts**

Note: I'm not posting from the debian pc

I followed several guides on using a second computer to download the firmware package but still, no joy.

I realised my phone supports hotspot over USB. Plugged in, `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and ran the following:

```
# apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-brcm80211

# modprobe -r brcmsmac ; modprobe brcmsmac
```

As on the debian site (I have checked that this is the right firmware model) but nothing changed; I'm still offline.

**Question**

I've been at this for a few hours, what am I doing wrong/what should I do?

I understand suggestive answering to promote learning, but please just give me a few commands and instructions, I really wanna get up and running without the need to have my phone plugged in.